Should I say "The teacher is calling for order/calling the students to order"?
As far as I know, a chairman might call people to order, or call for order in a meeting. But is this phrase applied in the classroom context?

The teacher is calling for order/is calling the students to order.


It would definitely be understood, but at least in American English, classrooms are not a context in which call (or bring) to order seems natural. More natural might be something like The teacher is telling the students to quiet down.
